# Port Closes Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a C# app that uses a serial port to talk to an embedded device. In the loop below, it reads the whole message then basically parses through it as it's coming in. This wasn't my code but I am developing something around it.

What is happening is that after a few seconds and a handful of messages I get an error on `port.Read(RxHolder, 0, 1);` saying InvalidOperationException, port is closed. The object exists, and nowhere has `port.close()` been called.

I'm running Visual C# 2010 express on a windows 7 64-bit machine if that adds any important information.

```
if (port.IsOpen)
{
    while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        // Read one byte
        port.Read(RxHolder, 0, 1);
        // Process it 
        ProcessRxedByte(RxHolder[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is there a dispose or using statement somewhere?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything along those lines, nothing seems to touch the port object. It gets into the loop, receives the entire message, then while checking if there are more bytes where it should jump out of the loop it throws the exception.

Comment: It is completely undiagnosable from the info you provided.  If you are absolutely sure that the code never calls Close or Dispose then suspect the driver for whatever device you are talking to.  Drivers that emulate serial ports are notoriously buggy.

Comment: I would gladly provide more information if you could point out what would help. This class is essentially the transport layer of an application, and it works correctly in another application on this same serial device, but when I took the code for this app it has started failing.